# iphone simulator resources not updating

Tags: iphone, xcode

My iPhone simulator refuses to update the resources which I edit.

After doing a "Clean" and build, the new resources were installed. On the second run it reinstalled the old ones. I have no idea where it's getting them from.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/` and look for your application to delete, or just delete that whole folder.

Comment: Done that, but it still comes up with the old files somehow.

Comment: This most likely means that XCode does not recognize your files as updated. Do you edit them outside of XCode?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Touch" command in the XCode context menu for the resource files. It helps sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have problem with caches, if the changes are not updating the simulators might need resetting.

Try quitting iPhone Simulator, then run xcrun in Terminal:

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```