# xCode 4 Adding Folders

Tags: xcode, xcode4, directory

In xCode 3 I could drag a folder into the project and say add references and it all works. When doing the same in xCode 4 it makes the folder blue and when trying to build it hangs at Attaching to .

I have tried everything but I couldn't resolve it. I have read :
[Xcode building and resources folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438898/xcode-building-and-resources-folders)

But that didnt help me. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: the folder was blue too in XCode3 when added as reference.

Comment: They all turned yellow on my screen when the 2nd option was checked see image below from Nick.

Comment: the second option turned them all yellow? Have you tried with a single folder? I just tested it and everything is fine. Maybe your XCode installation is screwed? Very strange. Running Xcode 4.0 Build 4A278b.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding a folder by dragging still works in XCode4. Look at the following dialog, the first alternative for Folders will turn the folder yellow, creating a smart group.

The second alternative will turn it blue referencing the folder directly.

[image]

Comment: Hello Nick, I will try the first option, i always checked the second options 'Create folder references for any added folder' that normally sufficed, perhaps the first option will work, i am gonna check.

Comment: new xcode project has .xcodeproj, .plist files and directory for project, but after checking out project from svn I get one folder with all files instead... is this the same issue as the one solved here?

Answer (score 6):

It is important not to call this directory ‘Resources’, as it seems to confuse Xcode into giving a lot of ‘Application is already installed’ errors.

Quoted from here: http://majicjungle.com/blog/123/
And worked for me on the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand why xCode doesn't have a default Resources folder it's a great way to keep it sorted.

Comment: just something i recently found out - loading images with imageWithContentsOfFile is 100% - 500% slower from imageNamed!