# File in folder that added using "Create folder references for any added folders" not updated

Tags: ios, app-bundle

I need to make a folder in app bundle to manage my resources file, images, sounds, etc. So I add my resources folder to xcode using "**Create folder references for any added folders**".

**Problem**

I got a problem when I want to update file in this folder (add file, rename, add sub folder), after I build it (both simulator and device) the folder didn't update to reflect my change, I have to `Product > Clean` to make it update. I wonder if I ship my product this will cause the problem or not, force user to reinstall my app every time I update my resources won't be a good thing to do.

Comment: What do you mean "force user to reinstall my app every time I update my resources"? When you update your resource of course you'll have to make a new release, a new version of your app, upload it to App Store and users will get automatic notification in their App Store application to update your app.

Comment: So if I don't forget to `Product > Clean` before ship this will work fine right ? Because normal build won't update my resources, so I afraid that this may affect the shipped version.

Comment: And if you _don't_ clean the project before building, then you actually see the old resources in your application? (If so, it should be a bug in XCode)

Comment: Yes thats the reason I ask this question. I just found someone getting the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1438898/147564).

Answer (score 0):

The resource files will be effectively copied in to your application bundle at compile time. If it is working after clean, and you see it working well on your phone, the same way the correct files will be copied to the application bundle when you Archive the App before submission. So I would not worry about this until you are sure to make a Clean also before Archiving at the time of submission.